# How to change an image path based on screen width?

Tags: jquery, image, path, window, width

I'm trying to change the folder that my images are read from depending on the window width.

I have two folders that contain the different image sizes and I'm wondering if anyone could give me any advice on how to change the path depending on the screens width.

If the screen is regular the `<img>` would look like

```
<img src="images/620x410/image1.jpg" alt="">
```

and If the screen was in the tablet width it would load

```
<img src="images/310x205/images1.jpg" alt="">
```

**310X205**

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
```

**620X410**

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `$(window).width();` to determine the size of the window, then set the src of the images accordingly:

```
$(function() {
  if($(window).width() <= 310) {
    $("img").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("images/620x410/", "images/310x205/"));
    });
  }
});
```

You should also note that if I start my browser window at a size of <= 310px, then resize it to above that, your images will still be the smaller version. You might want to consider using the resize event to combat that if required:
http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Shouldn't it be: $(window).width() <= 310?

Answer (score 32):

If CSS using media queries is an option for you, you could use a CSS only solution.

Add the media queries to your CSS similar to the below:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 310px) {
  .yourClass {
    content:url("images/310x205/image1.jpg");
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .yourClass {
    content:url("images/620x410/image1.jpg");
  }
}
```

Add the `myClass` to your effected image elements similar to the below:

```
<img class="yourClass">
```

You might need to tweak the values a little for your needs.

Comment: I didn't know about these - really interesting! Just for OP's benefit: IE7-IE9 don't support CSS media queries. A polyfill is available for this, but IE7 doesn't support the CSS content rule either so this will only work for IE8+ and most other versions of mainstream browsers.

Comment: @Blade0rz: Nice one +1. Didn't know about IE and `content`. An alternative could be to use a plain `div` with CSS targeting the `background-image` attribute instead but if media queries are not an option then detecting the width of the screen using JavaScript/jQuery might be a better choice in this scenario.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also works for when the screen gets resized.

Comment: Just a heads up for those needing cross browser support - this solution only works in Chrome. A JS solution that replaces out the src value is the way to go.

Comment: This page indicates content:url should work on all modern browsers:


 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: @KennyJohnson The `content` CSS only applies to `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements. Using it against `<img>` tags in this way is not a CSS standard and, apparently, only works in Chrome. That being said, there's no reason you couldn't use the CSS one in Chrome & the JS one in other browsers for the best of both worlds.

Comment: I will suggest a "mixed" solution (see my answer at bottom)

Answer (score 4):

I achieved a similar effect using Bootstrap Responsive utilities visible-xs and hidden-xs. I needed to use a different image set in a carousel depending on the size of the browser window.

```
        <div class="carousel slide hidden-xs" id="site-banner-big"  data-ride="carousel">   <!-- only show this carousel on large screens -->
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active"><center><img src="images/site-banner/large/image01.jpg" alt="Image"></center></div>
    <div class="item"><center><img src="images/site-banner/large/image02.jpg" alt="Image"></center></div>
    <div class="item"><center><img src="images/site-banner/large/image03.jpg" alt="Image"></center></div>
  </div><!-- end carousel-inner -->      
</div><!-- end site-banner-big -->

<div class="carousel slide visible-xs" id="site-banner-small"  data-ride="carousel">   <!-- only show this carousel on small screens -->
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active"><center><img src="images/site-banner/small/image01.jpg" alt="Image"></center></div>
    <div class="item"><center><img src="images/site-banner/small/image02.jpg" alt="Image"></center></div>
    <div class="item"><center><img src="images/site-banner/small/image03.jpg" alt="Image"></center></div>
  </div><!-- end carousel-inner -->      
</div><!-- end site-banner-small -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think waiting for DOM Ready (jQuery's $(document).ready)) is a good idea in this case.
Better use plain javascript:

```
if (screen.width < 620) {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) 
    {
        imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.replace("images/620x410/", "images/310x205/");
    }
}
```

Paste it at the bottom of your body tag.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to use the "image change path system" for different images inside the web page .
The idea is instead of change the "background" image (so  just a single image),
i would like to change the images path depending on the screen orientation :

as for php

```
$("#imageId").attr("src", "your new url here");
```

kind of this but dunno how

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) 
{
    .yourClass {
        content:url("images/landscape/");
    }
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    .yourClass {
        content:url("images/portrait/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use [resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if($(window).width() < 310 ) {
   $('img').attr('src','folder1'+filename);
}
if($(window).width() > 310 ) {
   $('img').attr('src','folder2'+filename);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have different images, so Nope option is the best. But in many cases you just want to have the same image in different size.
So perhaps a "mixed" solution:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 310px)
 {
 .yourClass_img1 {content:url("images/310x205/image1.jpg");}
 .img_list{width:100%;height:100%}
 }

 @media screen and (min-width: 620px) 
 {
 .yourClass_img1 {content:url("images/620x410/image1.jpg");}
 .img_list{width:60%;height:60%}
 }
```

With that, if some images need to be really different, the "content:url" will be effective, when the "width:height" will be good for images you just need to change the size.