# jQuery change folder with css change

Tags: jquery, css, html, media-queries

I am trying to change the folders that contain images when a div changes. I am using media queries to change a div on page load. I then need the jquery to check what size the div has been set to and then change the image folder accordingly. So for example if the max-width of my div is 700px I want jquery to change the string from photography/mobile/ to photography/fullscreen/ the original string is photography/fullscreen/stage.jpg but I do not want the whole string to change, only the word fullscreen, mobile or tablet. I am ok with css but my jquery is awful as I am currently learning!

Here is the code but the jquery is not working as the images are not changing when the media queries do:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Change Image!</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    #surround{position: relative; margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; max-width: 700px; height: 467px; border: 1px solid black;}
    @media screen and (max-width:800px){ #surround{max-width: 400px; height: 262px; border: 1px solid blue;} }
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px){ #surround{max-width: 200px; height: 133px; border: 1px solid red;} }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="surround">
  <image src="photography/fullscreen/stage.jpg" class="picture" />
</div>

</body>
</html>



$(document).ready(function(){
  if($("#surround").css("max-width") == "700px"){
  $("img").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src")("photography/fullscreen/"));
  });
  }

  if($("#surround").css("max-width") == "400px"){
  $("img").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src")("photography/tablet/"));
  });
  }

  if($("#surround").css("max-width") == "200px"){
  $("img").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src")("photography/mobile/"));
  });
  }
});
```

Comment: what is this line doing $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src")("photography/tablet/")); , can you also share from where you got this syntax?

Comment: @gnanz I cannot remember where I got the syntax to be honest! I have googled a solution and copied code from here and there. I then put it together to try and get it to work with my limited jquery knowledge. What I am trying to do is this:    http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries

Comment: BUT! The problem is I just want to change the actual folder as the site is a photography site and it would be far easier to change one line in a string over every image on every page! If the code above can work I think it would be the best solution?

Comment: try 'match' and 'replace' methods in jquery.

Comment: I think this is where I got the code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787306/how-to-change-an-image-path-based-on-screen-width

Comment: I am sure I have destroyed perfectly good code!

Comment: haha, bitter truth :-) if you know the minimal syntax, you wouldnt do this. thats what i try to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - it will replace the subdirectory part of the `src` attribute with the new `target_subdir` value. Also modified for encapsulation, caching selected elements, and code re-use (very important things in software development).

```
function changeImgSrc(target_subdir) {
    $("img").each(function() {
        var replacementSrc = $(this).attr("src").replace(
            /photography\/(\w*)\//,
            "photography/"+target_subdir+"/"
        );
        $(this).attr("src", replacementSrc);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $surround = $("#surround");
    var $surroundMaxWidth = $surround.css("max-width");
    if ($surroundMaxWidth == "700px") {
        changeImgSrc("fullscreen");
    }

    if ($surroundMaxWidth == "400px") {
        changeImgSrc("mobile");
    }

    if ($surroundMaxWidth == "200px") {
        changeImgSrc("tablet");
    }
});
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much for your time and code here Derek.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution, so you are new to jquery i dont want you to use copy paste.

as a first step, you try like

```
var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("photography/fullscreen/", "photography/tablet/");
  $(this).attr("src", src);
```

and look for other methods like using regular expressions, 'match' to make this statements for your problem. i will update this answer updated question with the progress

**Update:** As *Derek* gave complete code, you can take that code now.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I agree, I should not be copy / pasting code! I will follow your advice and learn more about regular expressions and methods...