# Switching background image then resizing image to 'new height' with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="section-one" class="section">
    <img id="section-one-img" style="width: 100%;" src="http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/section-one-pointers.jpg" />
    <div id="section-one-headline">
    <h1 class="main-headline"><span class="site-colour border-box">Your local CCTV Company</span> <br /><p class="headline-desc">with over 80 installation teams NATIONWIDE</span></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 880) {
    jQuery('#section-one-img').attr("src", 'http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/section-one-880px.jpg');
    }
    var imgHeight = jQuery('#section-one-img').height();
    jQuery('#section-one-img').height(imgHeight);
});
```

Although it loads the correct new image when the screen size is < 880, it doesn't set the new height of the image (the bottom section of the image is cut off).

Is there something wrong in my code to fix this?

Comment: What should the height of the new image be? Should it always have 100% width and remain in proportion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `load() function` for the image just after the `src` is changed:

Fistly. an element with the new image should be created (DOM) and calculate now its dimensions. So then we can adjust them:
Take a look to [jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/81r4ktj4/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/81r4ktj4/1/) for this reason

Implementation

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 880) {  
        var img = 'http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/section-one-880px.jpg';          

        var pic_real_width, pic_real_height;
        $("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
            .attr("src", img)
            .load(function() {
                pic_real_width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
                pic_real_height = this.height; // work for in memory images.
                /*alert(pic_real_width);
                alert(pic_real_height);*/
            });    
   jQuery('#section-one-img').attr("src", 'http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/section-one-880px.jpg');
          jQuery('#section-one-img').height(pic_real_height);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: still exactly the same?

Comment: I think it's somehow taking the height of the image of the original image as opposed to the new image

Comment: Yeah that works, although setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
  }, 10);
Wrapping the load function works as well, don't know which would be better, both do the same thing.

Comment: Timeout is not a good practise .i think the fiddle i provided is better and safe.Its your choice :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting all those fixed sizes, why not let CSS handle the height:

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 880) {
    jQuery('#section-one-img').attr("src", 'http://176.67.174.179/ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/section-one-880px.jpg');
    }
   // removed height setting here
});
```

CSS:

```
img {
    height: auto;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cktLr4h/

But why even use jQuery for this when you can show/hide different images with just CSS using media queries? [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16787749/124238)