# Could we replace images with srcset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is something that I have to fix it about changing **img** on **mobil** and **tablet** with another different images I couldn't fix it with jQuery **(I'm a beginner with jQuery)** and I'm trying to do it with `html5`.

Is there any way to change the image on the tablet and mobile versions with `srcset`? What can I do? Why is my code not working as expected? How can I change img src on **768px** and **480px** with jQuery? The image will be changed dynamically, that is why I don't want to do with just css (media queries).

[This is my another code](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/pRZZYQ)

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
   <img src="http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2017/htm/img/1.jpg"  
        srcset="http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2017/htm/img/2.jpg 1000w, http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2017/htm/img/3.jpg 768w,http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2017/htm/img/4.jpg 400w">      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? On your snippet I see a train front, which is image number 2, which means srcset does seem to work.

Comment: @recruit_man if you provide a `srcset` the user agent is free to pick the _best_ one at its own discretion. You can give another _hint_ using `sizes` attribute. What do you want to achieve? Different images according to display size using fixed break points?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change an image path based on screen width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787306/how-to-change-an-image-path-based-on-screen-width)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti actually I want to replace img source with another image  on tablet different image on mobile another different image must be change (sorry my english)

Comment: However `srcset` isn't intended to serve different content according to device you're using. It has been designed to provide a list of alternative images which browser can use to accommodate user preferences and bandwidth requirements. In addition with `sizes` it also serves to provide different images for different pixel densities (imagine a desktop low-res monitor Vs. a iPad2 display...). Incidentally _sometimes_ it may happen to seem related to device you're using...

Comment: Ouuw I understand thanks I guess I gotta try another way again with jquery

Comment: @recruit_man you have the answer in the question I linked before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add style to the image so that it is always 100% of the screen-width

```
<img src="http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2017/htm/img/1.jpg"  
 srcset="http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2017/htm/img/2.jpg 1000w, http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2017/htm/img/3.jpg 768w,http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2017/htm/img/4.jpg 400w" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: Hey Tony I'm talking about chancing image with different image I mean on wide screen nature image on tablet animal image on mobile sports image

Comment: Yes try replacing your code with mine it is working and it is replaced at the correct sizes